# How to look up values in Workbook2 using values from workbook1?

Tags: excel-2010

In workbook 1, I have a two columns of values.  The first column is a part number, and the second column is the quantity. Starting from the top, I would like to look up the part number from workbook1 and see if it's in workbook2.  If not, then go to the next part.  If so, then get the quantity from workbook1 and post that quantity in workbook2.

I am new to Excel, I have some knowledge of writing macros, but I am definitely a beginner.

Comment: Take a look at the VLOOKUP function.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using this: =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A13,[Book2.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1:$D$17,4,FALSE),0)

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of an answer:

According to OP, this worked:-

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A13,[Book2.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1:$D$17,4,FALSE),0)
```